# Sorting and array of objects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array that I need to sort by countries in alphabetical order:

```
data=[
    {
        "country": "China",
        "brands": {
            "abc": "123",
            "def": "123",
        },
        "day": "2020-04-16",
        "time": "2020-04-16T14:30:05+00:00"
    },
    {
        "country": "Zimbawe",
        "brands": {
            "abc": "123",
            "def": "123",
        },
        "day": "2020-04-16",
        "time": "2020-04-16T14:30:05+00:00"
    },
    {
        "country": "Africa",
        "brands": {
            "abc": "123",
            "def": "123",
        },
        "day": "2020-04-16",
        "time": "2020-04-16T14:30:05+00:00"
    }
]
```

I've tried this, so far:

```
data.sort()
```

and also this:

```
function(a, b){return a - b}
```

but it still returns the same order as the original array. So how do I sort this using country as the basis?

Comment: FYI, a multidimensional array has arrays as elements, not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` method

```js
const data=[{"country": "China","brands": {"abc": "123","def": "123",},"day": "2020-04-16","time": "2020-04-16T14:30:05+00:00"},{"country": "Zimbawe","brands": {"abc": "123","def": "123",},"day": "2020-04-16","time": "2020-04-16T14:30:05+00:00"},{"country": "Africa","brands": {"abc": "123","def": "123",},"day": "2020-04-16","time": "2020-04-16T14:30:05+00:00"}];

data.sort((a, b) => a.country > b.country ? 1 : -1);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` with function

```
 data.sort(function(a, b){
   var countryA=a.country.toLowerCase(), countryB=b.country.toLowerCase();
  if (countryA < countryB)
    return -1;
  if (countryA > countryB)
    return 1; 
});
```